# Windows Batch Scripts for Ant

Tags: windows, batch-file, ant

I am trying to get a project to deploy based on an ANT script generated class path. At this point, I got it to where it can run if I put everything into one directory, but how do I get it to run if my class path is in one directory with several smaller directories?

At this point, my jar is compiled and created.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:batch-file]'s.  You have not provided any code for to get help with either.

Answer (score 0):

What is the concrete problem? Could you send us a example? Are you using windows or linux?

There is no problem using sub-folders or folders in other location, you just have to indicate it. Example:

If you want to do something in the subfolder sb you have to call .\sb\whatyouwanttocall